# How to use extralight, semibold, black, … fonts of the Source Sans Pro typeface?

Tags: typefaces, sourcesanspro

The [Source Sans Pro package](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/sourcesanspro) provides many variants of the typeface. I’d like to use several of these fonts in the same document with pdflatex. There are package options like *semibold*, but these make all `\bfseries` semibold, so that I cannot use the bold font any more. How can I do something like the following (does not compile)?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sourcesanspro}
\begin{document}
{\extralightseries extra-light text}
{\semiboldseries semi-bold text}
{\bfseries bold text}
{\blackseries black text}
\end{document}
```

Here is the specimen:

[image: Source Sans Pro Type1 specimen]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The LaTeX kernel doesn't define all possible `\..series` commands, but you can add them yourself.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[default]{sourcesanspro}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\ebseries}{\fontseries{eb}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\texteb}{\ebseries}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\sbseries}{\fontseries{sb}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textsb}{\sbseries}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\elseries}{\fontseries{el}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textel}{\elseries}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\lseries}{\fontseries{l}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textl}{\lseries}

\begin{document}
{\sffamily\elseries extra-light text}

{\sffamily\lseries light text}

{\sffamily regular text}

{\sffamily\sbseries semi-bold text}

{\sffamily\bfseries bold text}

{\sffamily\ebseries black text}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I was not familiar with the `\fontseries{…}` commands, until I saw them in the [source code of the specimen PDF](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/sourcesanspro/doc/sourcesanspro-type1-specimen.tex) at CTAN five minutes ago ;-)